# why is prime-factorization-function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math, prime-factoring

I made a simple function in js that took one argument n, and factored it down to primes. However, when n is a product of duplicates of primes, it does not add the duplicates to the array of factors. For example the number 28. 28 is equal to 2*2*7 = 2^2 * 7. If I run my function factor(n) with n = 28, I want to get the following result: [2,2,7]. Instead, I get [2,7]. Can someone help me fix this??? Here's the function in js:

```
function factor(n) {

  var factors = []
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
  if (divisible(n,i)) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      factors.push(i)
     }
  factor(i)
   }
  }
   console.log(factors)
 }
```

THANKS!

Comment: In recursion, you usually need a base case that prevents an infite loop. As I see it, you are just logging the progress of adding all primes that are divisors of n to your array ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const primeFactors = N => {
  const smallestFactor = n => {
    if (n % 2 === 0) return 2;
    for (let k = 3; k * k <= n; k+= 2) if (n % k === 0) return k;
    return n;
  }
  let factors = [];
  let val = N;
  while (val !== 1) {
    let factor = smallestFactor(val);
    factors.push(factor);
    val /= factor;
  }
  return factors;
}
console.log(primeFactors(28));
```